# Passing all items in a dict as arguments in an efficient way

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a dict containing ten Pandas dataframes, and I want to stack these using Numpy. One way I could do this is by typing:

```
tensor = numpy.stack((dict[0],dict[1],...,dict[9]),axis=0)
```

However, as the number of items in the dictionary grows, this becomes very tiresome. Is there a way to pass all the items of dictionary at once, instead of manually typing out each element as above?

The following attempt at using unpacking gives me an 'TypeError: stack() keywords must be strings' error:

```
tensor = numpy.stack(**dict,axis=0)
```

What's an efficient and pythonic way to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `pandas.concat()`?.  Either way, this is interpreting the keys of `dict` as keyword arguments to the function.

Comment: I think you want `np.stack(*dict.values(), axis=0)`; there's probably some question about unpacking a dictionary that this is a duplicate of?

Comment: Brad: Thanks, I'll look into this. However I need to convert it to an ndarray later on, and as I understand pandas.concat will return a DataFrame in my case. 
Nathan: I get the same " stack() got multiple values for argument 'axis'" error as before using that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`**dict` is meant for a function that accepts keyword arguments. It unpacks the dictionary into a set of `key=value` arguments.  For example:

A dictionary like yours that uses integers as keys:

```
In [157]: dd = {0:np.arange(3),1:np.arange(10,13)}
```

A function:

```
In [158]: def foo(**kwargs): 
     ...:     print(kwargs) 
     ...:
```

Your error:

```
In [159]: foo(**dd)                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-159-965b46c2342b> in <module>
----> 1 foo(**dd)

TypeError: foo() keywords must be strings
```

It doesn't want to do: `foo(0=..., 1=...)`.

If I define the dictionary with string arguments that are valid variable names:

```
In [160]: dd = {'key0':np.arange(3),'key1':np.arange(10,13)}                    
In [161]: foo(**dd)                                                             
{'key0': array([0, 1, 2]), 'key1': array([10, 11, 12])}
```

So that explains the immediate error.

But that still won't work with `stack` which has the signature:

```
np.stack(arrays, axis=0, out=None)
```

I could use a dictionary to provide the keyword arguments, but not the `arrays` argument:

```
In [165]: pdict = {'axis':0, 'out':None}                                        
In [166]: alist = [np.arange(3), np.arange(10,13)]                              
In [167]: np.stack(alist, **pdict)                                              
Out[167]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Going back to the dictionary with numeric keys.  I can use `.values` to extract the arrays from the dictionary, and pass that, as a list, to `stack`:

```
In [171]: dd = {0:np.arange(3),1:np.arange(10,13)}                              
In [172]: list(dd.values())                                                     
Out[172]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([10, 11, 12])]
In [173]: np.stack(list(dd.values()))                                           
Out[173]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a TypeError is because your dictionary keys are not strings.

You can try passing your values into `np.stack()` using `dict.values()`.

```
tensor = np.stack(dict.values(), axis = 0)
```